# Multi Level Navigation on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, navigation

I would like to create multi level navigation or tree view on SPO from Site Pages. But from the Global navigation or site navigation, only two level is possible like

```
 Parent1
     --Child1
     --Child2
     Parent2
       --Child1
       --Child2
```

But what i want is like below structure, if it possible spfx please suggest with reference

```
Example1:

Parent
 --Child1
 --Child2

Example2:

Parent1
 --Child1
 --Child2
 Parent2
   --Child1
   --Child2

Example3:

Parent1
 --Child1
 --Child2
 Parent2
   --Child1
   --Child2
  Parent3
    --Child1
    --Child2
```

Nested Array:

```
if (v["ParentId"] == null) {
      const tree: ITreeItem = {
        key: v.Id,
        label: v["Title"],
        data: v["Link"],
        children: []
      }
   const tree1: ITreeItem = {
        key: v.Id,
        label: v["Title"],
        data: v["Link"],
        children: []
      }
   const tree2: ITreeItem = {
        key: v.Id,
        label: v["Title"],
        data: v["Link"],
        children: []
      }
      treearr.push(tree);
    }
    else {
      const tree: ITreeItem = {
        key: v.Id,
        label: v["Title"],
        data: v["Link"]
      }
```

Comment: Check this SPFx extension sample & let me know if it helps: [React Menu Footer Classic Modern](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-menu-footer-classic-modern)

Comment: Is it possible to have multi level like what i have described, and also found one sample, but how to make recursive navigation. Like above example with multi level on this spfx https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/14/tree-view-navigation-using-pnp-treeview-control-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/

Comment: Definitely possible with custom coding. You just need to add one nested level of menu items inside links array. In the link you shared there are 2 levels in links array (`this.state.TreeLinks`). Similary, you can try adding 3 levels of links in this data array.

Comment: I have updated the main question, is it something like that ?